# Transforming/repacking the results of a Slick query

Tags: scala, slick

I have what I hope is a simple question about Slick. Apologies if this is well documented - I may have overlooked something in my searching.

I have an aggregate query built as follows:

```
def doQuery(/* ... */) = for {
  a <- Query(TableA)
  b <- a.relationship.where // ...
  c <- b.relationship.where // ...
} yield (a, b, c)
```

This returns me a `Query[(A, B, C)]`.

I also have a case class:

```
case class Aggregate(a: A, b: B, c: C)
```

I'd like to transform my query to a `Query[Aggregate]` so my fellow developers can call `.list()` or `.firstOption()` and get a `List` or `Option` as appropriate.

I naturally went for the `.map()` method on `Query`, but it has an implicit `Shape` argument that I'm not sure how to handle.

Is this straightforward in Slick? We're using v1.0.1 at the moment but upgrading to 2.0 is also a possibility.

Best regards,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of playing around, I have concluded that this is not possible in Slick 1.

In Slick 2 you can use the `<>` operator to transform a projection assembled in the yield portion of the for comprehension:

```
def doQuery(/* ... */) = for {
  a <- Query(TableA)
  b <- a.relationship.where // ...
  c <- b.relationship.where // ...
} yield (a, b, c) <> (Aggregate.tupled, Aggregate.unapply)
```

This works as expected in conjunction with `.list` and `.firstOption`. I'm unsure what the consequences are of trying to use `.insert`, `.update` and `.delete`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify `doQuery`, then you just want to do `yield Aggregate(a, b, c)` instead of `yield (a, b, c)`.

Or, if you want to transform the result without modifying `doQuery`, then you can call `.map { case (a, b, c) => Aggregate(a, b, c) }` on the result of `doQuery`.

Comment: That's not going to work, I'm afraid. The values extracted from the query monads in the for comprehension are actually table aliases, not records parsed from the result of the query.

Comment: An extra note for clarity... your solution *will work* after calling `.list` or `.firstOption` on the query. At that point you're dealing with a query result `List` or `Option` as opposed to a `Query` so everything behaves exactly as expected.